# About the conjugated verb

Tags: verb, nominative, subject

In this sentence I can't figure out why it's "lass" not "lassen":

> Lass uns am Samstagabend ausgehen.

Also, if the subject is "uns" why it's not in the nominative case?

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is in imperative form. Imperative sentences usually have no explicit subject. Your sentence translates to English:

> Let's go out on Saturday night

Looking at that it follows the exact same grammatical pattern with only slightly different word order.

If you would want to make a simple statement, yes, then it would read differently with a proper subject "wir" and no form of "lassen" (English 'let') because there is no one from whom we need permission:

> Wir gehen am Samstag Abend aus.

But that's different in English, too: We go out on Saturday night.

Answer (score 2):

The subject of that sentence is *du*. But it's not posted because *lass* is second person singular imperative mood. The subject can't be anything else but *du*. You may argue that German doesn't drop pronouns usually, but this is an exception. Also, in colloquial speech pronouns **are** often dropped in German.

*Uns* is in accusative case because it's the object to *lassen.* It tells who is let. It doesn't tell who lets. That's *du*.

Be careful however:

- Lass (du) uns am Samstagabend ausgehen.

This adresses a single person in the familiar way. (“du”)

- Lasst (ihr) uns am Samstagabend ausgehen.

This adresses a group of persons in the familiar way. (“ihr”)

- Lassen Sie uns am Samstagabend ausgehen.

This addresses a single person or a group of persons in the distant way. (“Sie”) It's not in imperative mood but instead it's third person plural, posts the subject *Sie* (also mind the caps!) and has no topic in front so it looks similar to an imperative mood clause.

The tricky part is that they all mean the same: *Let (you) us go out on saturday night.* It's just different persons addressed in different ways.